Handling PostgreSQL trigger exceptions in a DELETE request in Spring Boot
I'm experiencing an issue with my Spring Boot web application when trying to handle exceptions thrown by a PostgreSQL BEFORE DELETE trigger during a DELETE request.
Here is the situation: When a DELETE request is made, a PostgreSQL trigger checks whether the item can be deleted. If it cannot be deleted, the trigger raises an exception. This exception should be caught by a GlobalExceptionHandler in Spring to display an appropriate error message on the front-end.
When I test the DELETE request using Postman, it works correctly and I receive the custom error message from PostgreSQL.

However, when the same request is made from the front-end, I get the original error message "Error while committing the transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction" instead of the detailed error message.
Trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iot.f_bd_reset_mepo_references()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    haveRule integer := 0;
    haveEchart integer := 0;
    haveAlarm boolean := false;
    ruleName character varying (20);
    echartName character varying (20);

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*), cond_is_active INTO haveRule, haveAlarm 
    FROM condition 
    WHERE cond_mepo_code = OLD.mepo_code AND client_code = OLD.client_code 
    GROUP BY cond_is_active;
    
    SELECT r.rule_code INTO ruleName
    FROM condition c
    JOIN event e ON c.cond_event_code = e.pk_event
    JOIN rule r ON e.pk_event = r.rule_event
    WHERE c.cond_mepo_code = OLD.mepo_code AND r.client_code = OLD.client_code; 

    SELECT COUNT(*), echart_code INTO haveEchart, echartName 
    FROM echartconfig 
    WHERE echart_pk_mepo = OLD.pk_measure_point AND client_code = OLD.client_code 
    GROUP BY echart_code;

    IF (haveAlarm = TRUE) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unable to delete measurement point because the alarm "%" is in progress.', ruleName;
    ELSIF (haveRule > 0) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unable to delete measurement point because it is referenced to the rule "%"', ruleName;
    ELSIF (haveEchart > 0) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unable to delete measurement point because it is referenced to the graph "%"', echartName;
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM alarm WHERE alarm_mepo_code = OLD.pk_measure_point AND client_code = OLD.client_code;
        DELETE FROM echartconfig WHERE echart_pk_mepo = OLD.pk_measure_point AND client_code = OLD.client_code;    
        DELETE FROM feedback WHERE sens_code = OLD.mepo_code AND client_code = OLD.client_code;    
    END IF;
    
    RETURN OLD;
END; 
$BODY$;

Global Exception Handler
import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(PSQLException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handlePSQLException(PSQLException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String message = ex.getServerErrorMessage().getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}


Why does the custom error message from PostgreSQL not get propagated correctly to the front-end but works fine in Postman?
Is there a better way to handle PostgreSQL trigger exceptions in Spring Boot to ensure that the error messages are correctly shown on the front-end?


Have you tried to CatchSQLExceptoin then use SQLException.getSQLState()?

I tried now. Using getSQLState() I get "P0001", using getMessage() I'm getting the entire error:
ERROR: Unable to delete measurement point because it is referenced to the rule "testdelete" Where: function PL/pgSQL f_bd_reset_mepo_references() row 25 at RAISE

As a solution you can create a mapper for sql state and a message in your app.

Thank you. I solved with your solution. It is anyway the best practice instead of returning the message from SQL

you are welcome, in case you will have any question you can tag me and I will tell my point of view

Thanks to comments above from Andrei Lisa, I changed the approach and now it is working.
Trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iot.f_bd_reset_mepo_references()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    haveRule integer := 0;
    haveEchart integer := 0;
    haveAlarm boolean := false;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*), cond_is_active INTO haveRule, haveAlarm
    FROM condition 
    WHERE cond_mepo_code = OLD.mepo_code AND client_code = OLD.client_code 
    GROUP BY cond_is_active;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO haveEchart
    FROM echartconfig
    WHERE echart_pk_mepo = OLD.pk_measure_point AND client_code = OLD.client_code
    GROUP BY echart_code;

    IF haveAlarm THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION SQLSTATE 'P0001';
    ELSIF haveRule > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION SQLSTATE 'P0002';
    ELSIF haveEchart > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION SQLSTATE 'P0003';
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM alarm WHERE alarm_mepo_code = OLD.pk_measure_point AND client_code = OLD.client_code;
        DELETE FROM echartconfig WHERE echart_pk_mepo = OLD.pk_measure_point AND client_code = OLD.client_code;    
        DELETE FROM feedback WHERE sens_code = OLD.mepo_code AND client_code = OLD.client_code;
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;


Global Exception Handler
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(SQLException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleSQLException(SQLException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String sqlState = ex.getSQLState();
        String customMessage = mapErrorMessage(sqlState);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private String mapErrorMessage(String sqlState) {
        switch (sqlState) {
            case "P0001":
                return "Unable to delete this measurement point because there is an alarm in progress.";
            case "P0002":
                return "Unable to delete this measurement point because it is referenced to a rule.";
            case "P0003":
                return "Unable to delete this measurement point because it is referenced to a graph.";
            case "P0004":
                return "Unable to delete this rule because there is an alarm in progress.";
            default:
                return "An unknown error occurred.";
        }
    }
    
}


